# Is it possible to insert a value into a file before it gets used in a terraform resource?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-connect

I'm deploying an Amazon Connect instance with an attached contact flow, following this documentation: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/connect_contact_flow

My contact flow is stored in a file, so I'm using the following:

```
resource "aws_connect_contact_flow" "general" {
    instance_id = aws_connect_instance.dev.id
    name        = "General"
    description = "General Flow routing customers to queues"
    filename     = "flows/contact_flow.json"
    content_hash = filebase64sha256("flows/contact_flow.json")
}
```

However my contact flow requires me to specify the ARN of an AWS Lambda function in one particular section:

*...*

```
"parameters":[
   {
          "name":"FunctionArn",
          "value":"<lambda function arn>",
          "namespace":null
    },
    {
          "name":"TimeLimit",
          "value":"3"
    }
],

</snip>
```

*...*

The value I would like to substitute into the JSON file at <lambda function arn> before the contact flow is created is accessible at

```
data.terraform_remote_state.remote.outputs.lambda_arn
```

Is there any way to achieve this? Or will I have to use the '**content =** ' method in the documentation linked above to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to use `filename` instead of `content`, you have to write the rendered template to some temporary file using [local_file](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/local/latest/docs/resources/file).

But using `content` with [templatefile](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/templatefile) directly for that would probably be easier. For that you would have to convert your `flows/contact_flow.json` into a template format:

```
"parameters":[
   {
          "name":"FunctionArn",
          "value":"$arn",
          "namespace":null
    },
    {
          "name":"TimeLimit",
          "value":"3"
    }
],
```

then, for example:

```
locals {

  contact_flow = templatefile("flows/contact_flow.json", {
                   arn = data.terraform_remote_state.remote.outputs.lambda_arn
                 })
}


resource "aws_connect_contact_flow" "general" {
    instance_id = aws_connect_instance.dev.id
    name        = "General"
    description = "General Flow routing customers to queues"
    content     = local.contact_flow
}
```

Comment: Thank you @marcin - this worked perfectly after changing $arn to ${arn}. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @NickTriantafillou No problem. Glad it worked out:-)